# Polynomial Regression - Machine Learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, dataset, fractional-polynomial

When I am working with polynomial regression in machine learning and
as the degree of polynomial increases, what is the reason for increased data accuracy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the reason that your model may have a higher non-linearity trend.

As you may know, polynomial regression works based on polynomial equations. And the polynomial equation gets curvy with an increase in the degree.

If you plot your dataset, you could see that the plot has a tendency towards a curvy shape. As you increase the degree of your polynomial regression model, it tends to fit better the data. As a result, the accuracy increases.

[Here](https://www.aionlinecourse.com/tutorial/machine-learning/polynomial-regression), you could find a detailed visual explanation of this phenomenon.